# Navigation Bar flashes when entering and leaving a video view

Tags: android

When I load a View with a video, the navigation bar at the bottom momentarily flashes and then slides down to go into immersive fullscreen. Is there a way to remove the momentary flashing when loading and unloading the view? 
video example - https://monosnap.com/file/smxhkhctOISN96rOZTaRJ3XtJJ7RP3

Also, I'm not sure if adding the view is causing this or if it's caused when the media player is added.

```
        dialog = new Dialog(cordova.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);


    // Let's create the main dialog
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setOnDismissListener(this);

    // Main container layout
    LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(cordova.getActivity());
    main.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    main.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    main.setVerticalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    videoView = new VideoView(cordova.getActivity());
    videoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | VideoView.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        );
    // videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    // videoView.setVideoPath(path);
    main.addView(videoView);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnErrorListener(this);
```

This app plays user generated slideshow slides which goes from iframes to video and back to iframes and so on... So I would like this transition to be seamless without the navigation bar appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added flags after the dialog initialization

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

The full code now looks like this

```
protected void openVideoDialog(String path, JSONObject options) {

    dialog = new Dialog(cordova.getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar);

    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog;

    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I came to this solution after getting a better understanding of how the dialog behaves in immersive mode [reading this article](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2014/06/android-immersive-mode-for-dialog.html)